# better way collection_check_boxes usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a Post/Category typical relationship (posts have many categories, so categories have many posts). I'm newbie using Rails 4 and trying to implement a `simple view` where i can check which categories matches the post topic.

PostsController

```
    ...
    params[:post][:categories].each do |category_id|
      @post.categories << Category.find(category_id)
    end
    ...
```

_form.html.erb

```
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :categories %>
        <%= f.collection_check_boxes :categories, Simpleblog::Category.all, :id, :title %>
     </div>
```

When i'm editing the Post `A`, check the category `1` and save, it works! but when i edit it again the check_box correspondent to the category `1` isn't checked! i know it is already saved in DB. So When i check the category again, its duplicate the records. Conclusion: I have Two Category `1` assigned to my post `A`. Two questions?

1) How i make check_boxes in `view` to persist the "check" for categories that's are already assigned to the post?

2) How can i prevent duplication between categories and posts relationship?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a great tutorial regarding checkboxes with a many to many association!
[RailsCast HASBTM Checkboxes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised?view=comments#comment_164591)

Do you have a relationship set up between your Post and Category model? This tutorial will walk you through it from start to finish. I was struggling with the same issue just a few days ago.